# Add input menulist arrow in css

Tags: css, input, prefix, appearance

i have a little problem here and i don't end up with a good solution so far, that's why i can handle some advice.
I have an input text and i want it to fake a menulist arrow. The appearance css style isn't working except on chrome so i have to find another way. I was thinking of adding a different image bg depending on the navigator. But here again, nothing i worth : the @-moz-document propertie is working only on firefox (i mean, the ms or o prefixes are not supported).
Is there a css way to reach what i want : having the good arrow style depending on the navigator used ?
Thanks for some clues :)

Here is the jsFiddle of what i've done so far for my `input` field : https://jsfiddle.net/Leminence/4zqaxLcr/

In this example, chrome understand to add a menulist arrow in my input field. Idem for mozilla (even if the image is not load here). Question is : how can i fake IE or Opera menulist arrow ?

Comment: What have you tried? Try this [helpful article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I bet that you want me to understand something ? I edit my post with a jsfiddle.